# Incompatible inter to pointer conversion

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

The following code generates compiler warning (below the code)

```
NSUInteger positionat = [_bhkButtons indexOfObject:sender];
BOOL val = (BOOL) [_searchModel.BHkNo objectAtIndex:positionat];
val = !val;

[_searchModel.BHkNo insertObject:val atIndex:positionat];
```

Incompatible integer to pointer conversion 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') to parameter of type 'id'

I'm a newbie to Objective - C. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `BOOL` is a primitive data type and arrays take in objects, you have to box/wrap the `BOOL` variable. You can use the `NSNumber` class for the same as shown below.

```
[_searchModel.BHkNo insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:val] atIndex:positionat];
```

Comment: Thnx. But how do I get val then? I mean should I typecast [_searchModel.BHKNo objectAtIndex:positionat] to NSNumber? Its giving me error.

Comment: The thing I want is inversion of the boolean value in the array

Comment: NSLog(@"value is %@",_searchModel[positionat]) will display the val.

Comment: Use this for unboxing/unwrapping, BOOL val = [[_searchModel.BHkNo objectAtIndex:positionat] boolValue];